# Django: Order_by 2 variables and Reverse the order of one of them

Tags: django, view

Simple question, when using the .reverse() in conjunction with .order_by() with 2 arguments, how can I only reverse one of the arguments?

For example:

```
some_model = Some_Model.objects.all().order_by(variable_1, variable_2).reverse(???)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`order_by` arguments are strings. You can simply prepend a `-` to reverse the order of one of them:

```
variable_2 = '-' + variable_2
Some_Model.objects.all().order_by(variable_1, variable_2)
```